# Jetpack Compose Lazy Column single selection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

I'm getting data from the server and displaying it in the list, each item can be selected with one click to display the button, but I cannot close it, I can only open it.

This is item of list class

```kotlin
data class Task(
    val deviceName: String,
    val deviceId: String,
    var selected :Boolean= Boolean,
)
```

this is data class

```kotlin
data class TaskStatus(
    val taskList: SnapshotStateList<Task>  = SnapshotStateList(),
    val selectedNumber: Int = -1,
)
```

My `ViewModel`

```kotlin
private val _status = MutableStateFlow(TaskStatus())
val status = _status.asStateFlow()

fun getList(){
  ...
  for(item in result){
    _status.value.taskList.add(task)
  }
}
fun selectTask(task: Task) {
  val list = _status.value.taskList
  val selectNumber = _status.value.selectedNumber
  val newSelectNumber = list.indexOf(task)
    if (newSelectNumber != selectNumber) {
      if (selectNumber != -1) {
        list[selectNumber].selected.value = false
      }
    }
  task.selected.value = !task.selected.value
  _status.update { it.copy(selectedNumber = newSelectNumber) }
}
```

My `LazyColumn`

```kotlin
...
LazyColumn(
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .weight(1F),
  verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(11.dp), contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
) {
  items(
    taskStatus.taskList,
    key = { it.deviceId }) { task ->
      Item(task)
    }
}

@Compose
fun Item(task:Task){
  Column(){
    Text(text = task.name)
    Text(text = task.deviceId)
    if(task.selected){
      Botton()
    }
  }
}
```

I can only show but not hide the button

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compile your code directly so I tried to make my own implementation. I added a callback which will be triggered from your Task Item

Your `TaskList` composable

```
@Composable
fun TaskList(
    taskList: SnapshotStateList<Task>,
    onSelected: (Task) -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(11.dp), contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
    ) {
        items(
            taskList,
            key = { it.deviceId }) { task ->
            Item(task) {
                onSelected(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `TaskItem` Composable

```
@Composable
fun Item(
    task:Task,
    onSelected: (Task) -> Unit
){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            onSelected(task) // selection callback
        }
    ){
        Text(text = task.deviceName)
        Text(text = task.deviceId)
        if(task.selected) {

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I mocked a `VieModel`

```
class TaskStateHolder {
    private val _status = MutableStateFlow( TaskStatus (
        taskList = mutableStateListOf(
            Task(
                deviceName = "Device 1",
                deviceId = "Device 1 ID"
            ),
            Task(
                deviceName = "Device 2",
                deviceId = "Device 2 ID"
            ),
            Task(
                deviceName = "Device 3",
                deviceId = "Device 3 ID"
            ),
            Task(
                deviceName = "Device 4",
                deviceId = "Device 4 ID"
            ),
        )
    ))

    val status = _status.asStateFlow()

    fun selectTask(task: Task) {
        _status.update {
            val list = it.taskList
            val newSelectNumber = list.indexOf(task)
            val iterator = list.listIterator()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val obj = iterator.next()
                if (task.deviceId == obj.deviceId) {
                    iterator.set(task.copy(selected = true))
                } else {
                    iterator.set(obj.copy(selected = false))
                }
            }

            it.copy(selectedNumber = newSelectNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

I modified your selectedTask function, executing _status `flow` udpates in a single pass using the list's iterator.

Usage somewhere outside (e.g "TaskScreen")

```
val tasks by stateHolder.status.collectAsState()
    Column {
        TaskList(tasks.taskList) {
            stateHolder.selectTask(it)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your method, but I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. I mean, the data has changed but the display has not changed. I can't even use your method. I can expand every item, but if you want to expand one of them, the other will be closed

Comment: I want to open only one item at a time

Comment: I tried my own implementation using the available codes you posted, please see the updated answer and the .gif showing single selection

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have completed the functions I need and optimized the code you gave me. I will  `selectedNumber ` -> `selectId`

Comment: thanks again,I have some small problems
How long will the data of the viewmodel remain? If two identical viewmodels are created, will the data be the same? Maybe I should send another question